# Como colocar highlights da linguagem certa nos códigos

Tags: suporte, syntax-highlighting

Eu gostaria de saber como colocar 'Sintax Highlights' nos códigos postados.
Como fazer o Stackoverflow reconhecer a linguagem de cada bloco de código?
Falo de fazer reconhecer de cada bloco, para poder inserir código de mais de uma linguagem no mesmo tópico, e não uma determinada linguagem para o tópico inteiro.

Comment: Na verdade, eu já tinha visto esse tópico, testei a técnica dele, e não vi diferença nenhuma

Comment: Bom, não sei o que você fez que não deu certo, mas garanto que funciona. Talvez crie uma pergunta explicando o que você fez para podermos analisar. Não sei se funciona aqui no Meta, mas caso sim, você pode usar esse tópico aqui para fazer testes: [Sandbox (ou “chiqueirinho”) de formatação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317/3117)

Comment: @JonatasAmaral Quando você diz que não vê diferença, a que se refere? É bom frisar que enquanto se está editando nem sempre o realce de sintaxe fica visível imediatamente (às vezes não aparece nada pra mim até que eu use o botão "Salvar"). Presumo que o mesmo vale para a mudança de uma linguagem pra outra. Você tem algum exemplo de situação em que o highlight não funcionou como deveria? Mesmo depois de salvar?

Comment: @mgibsonbr onde tem um botão "Salvar"?

Comment: @Math "Salvar edições" no caso de uma edição, ou "Publicar sua pergunta"/"Publique sua resposta". Em outras palavras, concluir a edição e publicar.

Comment: @mgibsonbr ah tá, é pq de tempos em tempos aparece escrito embaixo da resposta: "rascunho salvo", enquanto você ainda está formulando ela, mas não temos controle sobre isso. Achei que de alguma forma tinha como forçar o sistema a salvar seu rascunho. Valeu por explicar.

Comment: O teste eu fiz em um tópico meu (unico), no SOpt (não no meta)   

O que quero dizer com notar diferença é: depois de usar a técnica os highlights não mudaram, eles existem, mas são precários. A unica coisa que acontece é palavras da linguagem ficarem alaranjadas/avermelhadas, sem diferenciar o tipo de dado como ocorre no STen, e sem diferença entre as linguagem (Python e Javascript)